# Can I get scape characters still behave as such for a string provided by f:read() in Lua?

Tags: string, lua

I'm working on a simple localization function for my scripts and, although it's starting to work quite well so far, I don't know how to avoid scape/special characters to be shown in UI as part of the text after feeding the widgets with the strings returned by `f:read()`.

For example, if in a certain *Strings.ES.txt*'s line I have: `Ignorar \"Etiquetas de capa\"`, I'd expect backslashes didn't end showing up just like when I feed the widget with a normal string between doble quotes like: `"Ignorar \"Etiquetas de capa\""`, or at least have a way to avoid it. I've been *trial-and-erroring* with `tostring()` and `load()` functions and  different (surely nonsense ) concatenations like: `load(tostring("[[" .. f:read()" .. ]]"))` and such without any success, so here I'm again...

Do someone know if there is a way to get scape characters in a string returned by `f:read()` still behave as *special* as when they are found in a regular one?

Comment: Why don't you remove the backslashes? If you want to use `load` to apply string escapes, you must obviously use double quotes `"` rather than `[[` and `]]`, which don't accept escapes. `assert(load(('return "%s"'):format(f:read()))()` should work to "unquote" a string by executing it (be warned: don't use this for user input as it may be trivially exploited for remote code execution).

Comment: It works, thanks! Yeah, I guess I could simply remove the backslashes, but I wanted to keep both strings exactly equal to minimize any possible human error during translations (if I understood your question correctly). About using this method, I hope I'm not paying too much performance penalty only fo this, otherwise I could end up considering to just remove them... Regarding security, well, anyone could write or modify any hosting program's script anyway with such purpose, so I don't think that would be a (new) problem after all? But, again, I hope I got it... Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @LMD Oh, for the record, there is a missing parenthesis there so once added it would kept as: `assert(load(('return "%s"'):format(f:read())))()`. And, BTW, I suppose I could prescind of the `assert()` function as long as I ensure a "string" is the only thing that is going to be provided, isn't? But, on second thoughts, I think I may keep it anyway because although I didn't know about such function (thanks!), it seems to be very useful...

Comment: Yeah, the purpose of the assert function mainly is to cleanly propagate syntax errors in case the `load` fails rather than producing a cryptic "attempt to call a nil value" error. It is a common Lua idiom to you use `assert(f(...))` if `f` returns `nil, err` on failure to throw an otherwise "silent" error.

Comment: @LMD All good to know! Indeed, I had in mind to make it show some kind of text should something were wrong while obtaining the string and now I can do it using just that, instead of doing it in some other more "rudimentary" way. Well, thank you again! And, BTW, if by chance you wanted to take the time of copy-pasting your comment as an answer I'll mark as the right one without any doubt... Greetings!

Comment: @LMD  BTW... I've assumed all the time that, for making it work, the original string containing the scape characters has to be constructed using brackets this way: `[[Ignore \"Layer Tags\"]]` instead of the regular way using quotes: `"Ignore \"Layer Tags\""`. I can live with that cause it don't really make the texts different after all... But now I can't avoid wonder if couldn't be possible to make it also work with a source string constructed using quotes. I bet not, cause my understanding says me this way the scape characters would never really get passed to the function, but for asking...

Comment: Yes, that assumption was wrong. Only quoted strings (either single or double quotes) interpret escape characters. Bracketed strings **do not interpret escape characters**.

Comment: I've added an elaborate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to avoid [e]scape/special characters to be shown in UI as part of the text

What you want is to "unescape" or "unquote" a string to interpret escape sequences as if it were parsed as a quoted string by Lua.

> [...] with the strings returned by `f:read()` [...]

The fact that this string was obtained using `f:read()` can be ignored; all that matters is that it is a string literal without quotes using quoted string escapes.

> I've been trial-and-erroring with `tostring()` and `load()` functions and different [...] concatenations like: `load(tostring("[[" .. f:read()" .. ]]"))` and such without any success [...]

This is *almost* how to do it, except you chose the *wrong string literal type*: "Long" strings using pairs square brackets (`[` and `]`) *do not interpret escape sequences at all*; they are intended for including long, raw, possibly multiline strings in Lua programs and often come in handy when you need to represent literal strings with backslashes (e.g. regular expressions - not to be confused with Lua patterns, which use `%` for escapes, and lack the basic alternation operator of regular expressions).

If you instead use single or double quotes to wrap the string, it will work fine:

```lua
local function unescape_string(escaped)
    return assert(load(('return "%s"'):format(escaped)))()
end
```

this will produce a tiny Lua program (a "chunk") for each string, which just consists of `return "<contents>"`. Recall that Lua chunks are just functions. Thus you can simply call the function to obtain the value of the string it returns. That way, Lua will interpret the escape sequences for us. The same approach is often used to use Lua for reading data serialized as Lua code.

Note also the use of `assert` for error handling: `load` returns `nil, err` if there is a syntax error. To deal with this gracefully, we can wrap the call to `load` in `assert`: `assert` returns its first argument (the chunk returned by `load`) if it is truthy; otherwise, if it is falsy (e.g. `nil` in this case), `assert` errors, using its second argument as an error message. If you omit the `assert` and your input causes a syntax error, you will instead get a cryptic "attempt to call a nil value" error.

You probably want to do additional validation, especially if these escaped strings are user-provided - otherwise a malicious string like `str"; os.execute("...")` can trivially invoke a **remote code execution** (RCE) vulnerability, allowing it to both execute Lua e.g. to block (`while 1 do end`), slow down or hijack your application, as well as shell commands using `os.execute`. To guard against this, searching for an unescaped closing quote should be sufficient (syntax errors e.g. through invalid escapes will still be possible, but RCE should not be possible excepting Lua interpreter bugs):

```lua
local function unescape_string(escaped)
    -- match start & end of sequences of zero or more backslashes followed by a double quote
    for from, to in escaped:gmatch'()\\*()"' do
        -- number of preceding backslashes must be odd for the double quote to be escaped
        assert((to - from) % 2 ~= 0, "unescaped double quote")
    end
    return assert(load(('return "%s"'):format(escaped)))()
end
```

Alternatively, a more robust (but also more complex) and presumably more efficient  way of unescaping this would be to *manually* implement escape sequences through `string.gsub`; that way you get full control, which is **more suitable for user-provided input**:

```lua
-- Single-character backslash escapes of Lua 5.1 according to the reference manual: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.1
local escapes = {a = '\a', b = '\b', f = '\b', n = '\n', r = '\r', t = '\t', v = '\v', ['\\'] = '\\', ["'"] = "'", ['"'] = '"'}
local function unescape_string(escaped)
    return escaped:gsub("\\(.)", escapes)
end
```

you may implement escapes here as you see fit; for example, this misses decimal escapes, which could easily be implemented as `escaped:gsub("\\(%d%d?%d?)", string.char)` (this uses coercion of strings to numbers in `string.char` and a replacement function as second argument to `string.gsub`).

This function can finally be used straightforwardly as `unescape_string(f:read())`.

Comment: First off, thank you very much for the elaborated answer, it's much more than I expected and I've no words... OTOH, I'm afraid I'm in a bind after several hours trying to get to the bottom of the matter. One problem I have now is that if I feed my Localize function with the original English string **between brackets**, the translation takes place correctly because the string match with the one in the .txt file, BUT then turns out English language start displaying the escape characters in UI, which kinda makes sense since I'm basically telling it to use the string _literally_ after all.. (MORE)

Comment: (CONT'D) So, even thought I don't think it's possible, I've been trying to make it work by feeding Localize function with the string **between quotes** (as I hinted in my last comment above), but then the escape characters never really get inside the function and, again, the translation fails because original English strings don't match anymore... Well, that's one problem, the other is I can't make work your alternative second solution and I don't know why, It's like I always get the very same string returned by it no matter if it contains escape characters or not, I'll continue trying tho...

Comment: BTW, I also realized even the official Localize function of the hosting app presents this escape characters problem and ends up showing them in UI for the translated strings. It's kind of funny, cause I took the idea of start using escape characters in my _nested quoted_ strings (instead of combinate single/double quotes) cause I saw that's how they did it and I always try to preserve style as well as learn from the best... Well, that makes me wonder if won't be the own app which is complicating things somehow "disrupting" strings at some point under the hood? It surely won't make sense, but..

Comment: @Ramon0 which software is this? Without the API docs (and ideally the sources) at hand it's hard to help. As for the second snippet, it looks like I forget the escape for double quotes in the table... Fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: It's a 2D animation program called "Moho" (I dream with the day I get enough reputation here to can create a tag for it ), it uses internally Lua 5.2.4 and its API can be consulted [HERE](https://mohoscripting.com/). Besides that, there're some other reference files that come with it but I don't think they're online... Although I doubt there's a problem with it after all but in concept; I mean, in the end I'm treating to pass e.g. `"Ignore \"Layer Tags\""` into my function (remember now I know I can't use `[[Ignore \"Layer Tags\]]` cause that way escape chars appear in the English UI) (MORE)

Comment: (CONT'D) ...and, as far as I know, that seems not possible cause the function is always going to get the string without the escapes cause that's what they're meant to (hope it makes sense). BUT (assuming I'm right), what seems to be the way to go is your alternative method. I'm not getting to make it work yet with the "escapes" table for some reason, but if I use it e. g. this way: `origString = s:gsub('"', '\\"')` it obviously reconstructs the original string by adding again the \ before any " and then everything starts working! It surely needs more elaboration, but it's something :) THANKS!

Comment: Therefore, since for solving the problem (or make it work for now at least, given that it'll surely require a little more work) I've had to finally use a combination of your both suggestions, that is: make use `origString:gsub('"', '\\"')` for _restoring_ the lost escapes when passing to the Localize function and `transString = assert(load(('return "%s"'):format(v)))())` for ensuring they don't end up appearing in UI after returned from the function... I'm (of course) going to accept this super useful answer feeling immensely grateful for all the provided help. Greetings!